# ERROR: ‘GetNamedPipeClientProcessId’ was not declared but Winbase is included

Tags: c, windows, winapi, cygwin, pipe

I'm using Windows 10 (`1709`) with cygwin. Here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <Winbase.h>

int main()
{

    HANDLE hPipe;
    char buffer[1024];
    DWORD dwRead;
    PULONG ClientProcessId = NULL;


    hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\Pipe"),
                            PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
                            PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
                            1,
                            1024 * 16,
                            1024 * 16,
                            NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
                            NULL);
    while (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) != FALSE)
        {
             if (GetNamedPipeClientProcessId(hPipe, ClientProcessId) != 0)
             {
                  printf("ID -> %lu\n", ClientProcessId);
                  fflush(stdout);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a little test program which just creates a server pipe and starts to listen to it, and when someone gets connected it just prints pipe client processes ID.

The problem I'm having is

```
error: ‘GetNamedPipeClientProcessId’ was not declared in this scope
          if (GetNamedPipeClientProcessId(hPipe, ClientProcessId) == 0)
```

Since I got `Winbase.h` included it was really strange, I opened `Winbase.h` and found declaration of this function:

```
#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)

WINBASEAPI
BOOL
WINAPI
GetNamedPipeClientProcessId(
    _In_ HANDLE Pipe,
    _Out_ PULONG ClientProcessId
    );
```

After quick google search I've found that `WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)` is just to determine what platform you have and what API's are suitable for your platform ( [winapifamily.h](https://github.com/jp9000/OBS/blob/master/extras/winapifamily.h)). Seems like it function should be available on desktop platforms.

I've got little confused here. What else could be the problem? thanks.

Comment: this api is declared if `#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)`, so guess your `_WIN32_WINNT < 0x0600`. and *I'm using Windows 10 (1709)* - this not play any role at all

Comment: you are right, I printed `_WIN32_WINNT` and it's 502. Is there any way that I can update api?

Comment: simply `#define  _WIN32_WINNT   0x****` **before** include `#include <windows.h>`. or add `#include <sdkddkver.h>` at very begin. so you in general need yourself define `_WIN32_WINNT` to some version before any includes

Comment: @Ojs See [Setting WINVER or _WIN32_WINNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx#setting_winver_or__win32_winnt) and [Modifying WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt)

Comment: The program is windows one, not a cygwin/unix one. As such you should use a windows compiler (like mingw) not the cygwin gcc compiler.